# Ehcache miss counts

Tags: caching, statistics, ehcache

These are the statistics for my Ehcache.

I have it configured to use only memory (no persistence, no overflow to disk).

```
cacheHits = 50
onDiskHits = 0
offHeapHits = 0
inMemoryHits = 50
misses = 1194
onDiskMisses = 0
offHeapMisses = 0
inMemoryMisses = 1138
size = 69
averageGetTime = 0.061597
evictionCount = 0
```

As you can see, `misses` is *higher* than `onDiskMisses + offHeapMisses + inMemoryMisses`. I do have statistics strategy set to best effort:

```
cache.setStatisticsAccuracy(Statistics.STATISTICS_ACCURACY_BEST_EFFORT)
```

But the hits add up, and the difference between misses is rather large. Is there a reason why the misses do not add up correctly?

---

This quesiton is similar to [Ehcache misses count and hitrate statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937512/ehcache-misses-count-and-hitrate-statistics), but the answer attributes the differences to the multiple tiers. There is only one tier here.

Answer (score 3):

I'm almost certain that you're seeing this because inMemoryMisses does not include misses due to expired elements.  On a get if the value is stored, but expired then you will not see an inMemoryMiss recorded, but you will see a cache miss.